# rgb2gray returns a blank white image, whereas image(I) returns the image correctly

Tags: image-processing, matlab

here's my code:

```
I = imread(fullfile(vl_root,'data','cup1.jpg')) ;
%returns a picture of a cup
image(I)
colormap gray;
%returns a white blank picture
image(rgb2gray(I))
```

what is strange is, the following code works for me:

```
    I = getsnapshot(vid);
 %returns a picture of a snapshot
    image(I)
    colormap gray;
    %returns a black and white  picture
    image(rgb2gray(I))
```

from this I can only assume that there is some kind of difference between the two image types, but I can't seem to pinpoint why. They are all

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I run your code, and apparently 'colormap gray' creates a colormap of dimensions 64x3, which are not enough for the 8-bit grayscale image, which in turns makes the colors look truncated.
I used

```
        colormap([linspace(0,1,255)' linspace(0,1,255)' linspace(0,1,255)'])
```

and it worked fine.

I do not have a camera, so I cannot verify the second part, but perhaps the camera image is a low-intensity one?